# file created yesterday or today

Tags: unix, loops, if-statement, filesystems

I have to check if file name does not some pattern and also is created within last 2 days, then what should be done?

```
for file in ABS*; do
if [[ "$file" != *.bz2 ]] **AND IS CREATED YESTERDAY Or TODAY**
then
MY WORK
fi
done
```

What can be condition for file created yesterday or today only?

Comment: Take a look at the `find` command and its options for this. Start by reading its man page: `man find`

Comment: Yes i know if i do find . -ctime -2 then it will work, but how to apply this as a condition in if statement?

Comment: The `find` command _is_ a condition, if you put it that way. You get back a list of matching files, so they _all_ fulfill the condition. You don't need an _if_ any more. Just process the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is

```
for file in $(find ./ABS* -mtime -2 ! -name *.bz2); do
    MY WORK
done
```

The -mtime -x flag means any files modified fewer than x days ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -mtime -2 -type f \( -name "ABC*" ! -name "*.bz2" \)
```